# How to deserialize complex object into flat using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have XML like:

```xml
<root>
  <prop1>value1</prop1>
  <prop2>value2</prop2>
  <data>
    <prop3>value3</prop3>
    <prop4>value4</prop4>
  <data>
</root>
```

and I would like to deserialize it into an object like:

```
class xyz
{
    string prop1;
    int prop2;
    string prop3;
    int prop4;
}
```

How should I mark prop2 and prop3 with `XmlElement`-Attribute?

Comment: Do you have control of the XML format/schema? There are XML serialization techniques that can be looked into if your data conforms to a schema.

Comment: deserializing would be an **overkill**..use `linq2xml`

Comment: No, I have mnot. XML schema is given. :-(

Comment: I have tried to rewrite XmlSerializer tu be able to use xPath as a parameter of XmlElement attribute. But I got lost in implementation. It is not so easy as I have expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq 2 Xml for this (assuming you'll fix your xml and add `public` to your field definitions )

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // XDocument.Load(filename);
var x = new xyz()
    {  
        prop1 = xDoc.Root.Element("prop1").Value,
        prop2 = (int)xDoc.Root.Element("prop2"),
        prop3 = xDoc.Root.Element("data").Element("prop3").Value,
        prop4 = (int)xDoc.Root.Element("data").Element("prop4"),
    };
```

Comment: Yes, I can, but imagine, there are thousands of properties. Code will be to long i nace of this solution. But it works for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend this approach:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
[Serializable]
public class RootElement
{
    [XmlElement("prop1")]
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("prop2")]
    public string prop2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("data")]
    public DataElement data { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("data")]
[Serializable]
public class DataElement
{
    [XmlElement("prop3")]
    public string prop3 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("prop4")]
    public string prop4 { get; set; }
}

var yourObject = (RootElement)new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootElement)).Deserialize("your xml goes here");
```

You access your properties like this:

```
yourObject.prop1
yourObject.prop2
yourObject.data.prop3
yourObject.data.prop4
```

If you want deserialize xml to flat structure, I think it is not possible by default. You can write your own implementation of IXmlSerializable or better override some methods of XmlSerializer.

Comment: I'd like to avoid that. I'd like to have just one object in flat structure. There are more nested section and it will leads to implementation with to many objects.

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions in his question's title that he wants to deserialize into a "flat" object.